# gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: networking, 20.04, nginx, django

I want to use a digitalocean droplet to host a django site. I'm trying to get the app running on the server with gunicorn and nginx, I'm getting a 502 error when I try to hit the server from my browser and I've been trying to figure out what's going on.

I have been following [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-a-django-web-app-on-digitalocean-ubuntu-20-04-server-a3c082d5294d) tutorial. My droplet is Ubuntu 20.04.

This is my `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

This is my `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/mysite
ExecStart=/home/root/mysite/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          mysite.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can run `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 mysite.wsgi` and `python manage.py runserver` with no errors showing up. When I run `sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket`, the socket appears to be active.

However, when I run `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`, I get the following:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-03-14 05:25:01 UTC; 4min 53s ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
    Process: 74292 ExecStart=/home/root/mysite/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind>
   Main PID: 74292 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Mar 14 05:25:01 mysite systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Mar 14 05:25:01 mysite systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200>
Mar 14 05:25:01 mysite systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I am using gunicorn version 20.0.2. s

From looking at the nginx error logs, I keep getting the following error when I try to access the site:

```
2023/03/14 05:12:12 [error] 72896#72896: *22 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed 

(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,server

mysite.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", 

host: "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The tutorial says to use `User=yourusername` and `WorkingDirectory=/home/yourusername/path-to-your-projectdir` yet you are using `User=root` and `WorkingDirectory=/home/root/mysite` - these are not directly analogous since root's home directory (at least by default) is `/root` not `/home/root`.